# ActionPerformed method doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I want to execute a method inside an ActionPerformed method that is associated to a button, but doesn't work. I research during a lot of time but I can't detect the error.

This is my code:

```
/**
 * Método que crea un nuevo usuario en el sistema
 * y lo guarda en el arrayList de usuarios
 */
public static void crearUsuario()
{      
    JPanel panelCrearUsuario = new JPanel();
    JDialog frame = new JDialog();     

    //label nuevo usuario
    panelCrearUsuario.add(new JLabel("Nuevo Usuario: "));

    //textbox nuevo usuario
    JTextField jtNombreUsuario = new JTextField(15);
    panelCrearUsuario.add(jtNombreUsuario);

    //label DNI
    panelCrearUsuario.add(new JLabel("DNI usuario: "));

    //textbox DNI
    JTextField jtDNIUsuario = new JTextField(15);
    panelCrearUsuario.add(jtDNIUsuario);

    //botón crear usuario
    JButton JButtonCrearUsuario = new JButton("Crear usuario");
    panelCrearUsuario.add(JButtonCrearUsuario);

    frame.getContentPane().add(panelCrearUsuario); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(420, 460);
    frame.setModal(true);
    frame.setVisible(true); 

    Usuario u = new Usuario();
    u.setNombre(jtNombreUsuario.getText());
    u.setDNI(jtDNIUsuario.getText());

    JButtonCrearUsuario.addActionListener(new ActionListener()   {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Debbuging the IDE doesn't enter here :(
            System.out.println("blablabla");
            JButtonCrearUsuarioEvento(u);
        }

    });

}
```

I tried too with this way:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println("blablabla");
            JButtonCrearUsuarioEvento(u);

        }
    };

    JButtonCrearUsuario.addActionListener(listener);
```

Can something help me? Where is the error? :(
I really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Your debugger doesn't get in your actionPerformed? You don't see the message 'blablabla'? You don't see the button on your screen?

Answer (score 2):

add action Listener before adding JButton to panel, and displaying jdialog, then it will work: change code like below:

```
    /**
     * Método que crea un nuevo usuario en el sistema
     * y lo guarda en el arrayList de usuarios
     */
    public static void crearUsuario()
    {      
        JPanel panelCrearUsuario = new JPanel();
        JDialog frame = new JDialog();     

        //label nuevo usuario
        panelCrearUsuario.add(new JLabel("Nuevo Usuario: "));

        //textbox nuevo usuario
        JTextField jtNombreUsuario = new JTextField(15);
        panelCrearUsuario.add(jtNombreUsuario);

        //label DNI
        panelCrearUsuario.add(new JLabel("DNI usuario: "));

        //textbox DNI
        JTextField jtDNIUsuario = new JTextField(15);
        panelCrearUsuario.add(jtDNIUsuario);

        //botón crear usuario
        JButton JButtonCrearUsuario = new JButton("Crear usuario");

 JButtonCrearUsuario.addActionListener(new ActionListener()   {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Debbuging the IDE doesn't enter here :(
                System.out.println("blablabla");
                JButtonCrearUsuarioEvento(u);
            }

        });

        panelCrearUsuario.add(JButtonCrearUsuario);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panelCrearUsuario); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(420, 460);
        frame.setModal(true);
        frame.setVisible(true); 

        Usuario u = new Usuario();
        u.setNombre(jtNombreUsuario.getText());
        u.setDNI(jtDNIUsuario.getText());



    }
```